# Send Email using Rails4 on Heroku

Tags: email, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I make the setting to send Emails using an App on Heroku with Rails 4?

I'm checking some stating that I have an SMTP account, but my app and only a test for now, I can not send emails without owning a domain account with smtp?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku will work with [ActionMailer](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) if it's set up properly.  If you want to use a Gmail account or similar, I have followed [these instructions](http://www.azgaard.com/2012/06/05/sending-email-from-rails-using-smtp-on-heroku/) before and it has been successful.

If you're looking for testing, I'd highly recommend checking out the [Mailtrap add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/mailtrap) as it is extremely easy to set up and use, and it catches all email sent by your app in a nice UI where you can troubleshoot and debug.